# react-native-in-app-utils not added to NativeModules

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I ran:

```
react-native install react-native-in-app-utils
```

and it completed successfully. I added the import to my code:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
const { InAppUtils } = NativeModules
```

No errors occur in building and starting but *NativeModules* is empty and *InAppUtils* is undefined.
I have used this successfully in RN 0.48; this is on RN 0.55.

Is there some step I am missing?

Comment: are you using expo or CRNA?

Comment: I am using CRNA.

Comment: I misspoke here. I am using react-native init

Answer (score 1):

Documentation details for [react-native-in-app-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils) is misleading  regarding Linking.

Install Library (react-native-in-app-utils) using **rnpm**. you need to install [rnpm](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm).

1.`npm install rnpm -g`
2. `rnpm install react-native-in-app-utils`

**rnpm** will auto link your library for IOS.

---

**SUGGESTION**

### Do not install library using Yarn , npm and `react-native install react-native-in-app-utils`

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Not right away, I removed react-native-in-app-utils from package.json, rebuilt all of node_modules, and used rnpm to install react-native-in-app-utils. Still not working. Then I restarted xcode and that did it. I forgot how finicky xcode can be. I'm not sure if the rebuilding was necessary or not. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user1460092 In my case using **rnpm** was working fine .

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-in-app-utils` requires you to have created your app with 'react-native init`. Or, you have to eject from CRNA.

CRNA can't use native modules unless you eject/detach (similar to expo, as they're interrelated):

- https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils/issues/130
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html